# Cursor loader android not refreshing

Tags: android, android-cursoradapter

I am new with cursor loader.I want refresh cursorLoader at a specific time to refresh my list view ie,
i am executing different queries from database to refrsh data in list.

```
    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle arg1) {

    switch (id) {
    case 0:
    Log.i("IN LIST AGAIN: SORT BY DISTANCE","DEalFragment/fillListAgain():"+id);
    return new CursorLoader(getActivity(), // Parent activity context
    DataBaseConstants.TableURi, null, // Projection

        "" + DataBaseConstants.ColumName_1 + " = 'L'" /*+ " AND "
    + DataBaseConstants.ColumName_2 + " != 0"*/, // selection
            null,// No selection arguments
    DataBaseConstants.C_DIST + " ASC LIMIT 6"// Default sort order
        );

    case 1:
            return new CursorLoader(getActivity(), // Parent activity context
        DataBaseConstants.TabelURi, null, // Projection

            "" + DataBaseConstants.C_LTY_PROMO_TYPE + " = 'L'" + " AND "
            + DataBaseConstants.C_LTY_PROMO_ID_PARENT + " != 0", // selection

            null,// No selection arguments
                DataBaseConstants.C_DIST + " ASC  LIMIT 25"// Default sort order
                );
            default:


                return null;
        }
            }
```

In first case i need 6 data from db and in second case i need 25 data. I am calling

```
getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
```

for the  first case on the second case i am calling

```
    getLoaderManager().initLoader(1, null, this);
```

I am not getting the right result from this . Can you help to find what is the error

Comment: Post your content provider query function

Comment: I am not using content provider,I am using loader  callback and simple cursor adapter

Comment: So how are you querying the database??

Comment: As my code above in onCreateLoader().I just called the queries,you can see queries on the above code inside switch case statement,Both queries are there.

Comment: That is not how cursorloader works. I would suggest you to go through some examples.